# When can we take infinite limits accross an inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

$\newcommand{\scrF}{\mathscr{F}}$
I'm trying to understand the following statement and it's proof. First some definitions

**Definitions:** If $\Omega$ is a set and $\mu^\ast$ is an outer measure defined on $\Omega$, then we denote $\scrF_{\mu^\ast}$ to be the collection of all $\mu^\ast$ measurable sets in $\Omega$. Note that this is a field in $\Omega$.

**Proposition:** Let $\Omega$ be a set and $\mu^\ast$ an outer measure defined on $\Omega$. Let $(E_n)$ be a sequence of disjoint sets in $\scrF_{\mu^\ast}$, then for any $T \subseteq \Omega$ we have that
$$
\mu^\ast \left(T \cap \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n \right)\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu^\ast (T \cap E_n).
$$

To prove the statement we argue via an induction on $n$ to arrive at
$$
\mu^\ast \left(T \cap \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^k E_n \right)\right) = \sum_{n=1}^k \mu^\ast (T \cap E_n), (\forall k \in \mathbb{N}).
$$
Getting here is fine to me, but to finish the proof I have an issue. We then note that
$$
T \cap \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n \right) \supseteq T \cap \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^k E_n \right),
$$
and so by monotonicity of the outer measure we have that
$$
\mu^\ast \left(T \cap \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n \right)\right) \geq \mu^\ast \left(T \cap \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^k E_n \right)\right) = \sum_{n=1}^k \mu^\ast(T \cap E_n),
$$
where the equality is from our induction. We next say that *letting $k \rightarrow \infty$ on the RHS* gives the desired inequality. There's probably some basic Analysis that I'm forgetting, but why do we get to just let $k$ approach infinity in the limit here; i.e what guarantees nothing goes wrong? Thanks in advance for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "basic result" you may be forgetting is that for any convergent sequence $(a_k) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we have the following: if there exists a $b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a_k \leq b$ for every $k$, then $\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k \leq b$ also. This limit inequality also holds trivially if $b = \infty$, or if any $a_k$ is actually infinite.

In your case, $b$ is the fixed (extended) real number $\mu^*\left(T\cap\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right)\right)$, and $(a_n)$ is the sequence of partial sums $a_k = \sum_{n=1}^k \mu^*(T\cap E_n)$. By definition of an infinite series,
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu^*(T\cap E_n) = \lim_{k\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^k \mu^*(T\cap E_n) = \lim_{k\to\infty} a_k.
$$

So because you showed $a_k \leq b$ for all $k$, the above limit theorem applies to give us
$$
\mu^*\left(T\cap\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right)\right) = b \geq 
\lim_{k\to\infty} a_k =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu^*(T\cap E_n).
$$

By the way, if you were concerned about the inequality going only one way, the other way follows by subadditivity:
$$
\mu^*\left(T\cap\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty E_n\right)\right) = \mu^*\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (T \cap E_n)\right) \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mu^*(T\cap E_n).
$$

Comment: Ah perfect thanks! I guess it wasn't clicking that it was an upper bound for the sequence of partial sums! And I do see that sub-additivity implies the other direction!

Comment: Just to be sure I've understood everything can you tell me if this logic works? To justify that the limit of the partial sums exists, note that we've bounded the partial sums above, and because these partial sums are increasing since an outer measure is positive, we are guaranteed that the infinite sum converges. Moreover because each term is bound above the series must converge to a limit less than the bound as you mentioned.

Comment: That's essentially right. One issue is that the infinite sum may be infinite. But the key is that the summands are all nonnegative. Hence if the partial sums were bounded (in $\mathbb{R}$), the monotone convergence theorem for sequences says the infinite series converges (again, in $\mathbb{R}$). But if they aren't bounded, then they tend to infinity, and we can just "define" the infinite sum to be infinite.

Comment: Oh yeah because the outer measures have codomain $[0,\infty]$ fair enough. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Recall that for a non-decreasing sequence of real numbers, we have $\lim a_n = \sup \{a_n\}$, and an analogous statement holds for non-increasing sequences. In particular, $\limsup a_n$ is the limit of a certain non-increasing subsequence of $a_n$, and is thus the supremum of said subsequence. Hence if $x\geq a_n$ for all $n$, then $x\geq \sup \{a_n\}=\limsup a_n$.